# how to use old profile picture if no image selected in php

Tags: php, mysql, post

this is my code updating data. How is it possible to use old image if no image is selected?

its a profile page when someone updates his profile but don't select the image for update then old image should be remained there..

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['update_user'])){

//getting text data from field

$update_id = $user_id;
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$designation = $_POST['designation'];
$username = $_POST['username'];


$location="images/users/";
$name=$_FILES['user_img']['name'];
$temp_name=$_FILES['user_img']['tmp_name'];
if(isset($name)){
move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$location.$name);
}
else
{
    echo $user_img;
}

$update_product = "update user set FullName='$fullname',Designation='$designation',UserName='$username',User_Pic='$name' where Id='$update_id'";

$run_product = mysqli_query($con, $update_product);

if ($run_product){
echo"<scripy>alert('Update Successful')</script>";
echo "<script>window.open('user_manage.php','_self') </script>";
}

}

?>
```

Comment: To retain the old image, you need not update the `User_Pic` field in the `user` table.

Comment: i want both option if user need he can change picture or retain old image.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to fetch the existing user details from the database and check if the user already has a profile picture.

Next, if the user has uploaded a new image, then you can delete the old profile picture using `unlink()` function. If the user has not uploaded a new picture, you can retain the old picture.

See the code below.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['update_user'])){

  //getting text data from field

  $update_id = $user_id;
  $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
  $designation = $_POST['designation'];
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $location="images/users/";

  //Fetch user details
  $query = "SELECT User_Pic FROM user WHERE Id=" . $update_id;
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
  $row = false;
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  }

  if (isset($_FILES['user_img'])) { //User uploaded new image
    if ($row) {
      unlink($location . $row['User_Pic']); //Delete old pic
    }
    $name=$_FILES['user_img']['name'];
    $temp_name=$_FILES['user_img']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$location.$name);
    $update_product = "update user set FullName='$fullname',Designation='$designation',UserName='$username',User_Pic='$name' where Id='$update_id'";
  } else { //User did not upload image
    if ($row) {
      echo $location . $row['User_Pic']; //Echo current image path
    }
    $update_product = "update user set FullName='$fullname',Designation='$designation',UserName='$username' where Id='$update_id'";
  }

  $run_product = mysqli_query($con, $update_product);

  if ($run_product){
    echo"<scripy>alert('Update Successful')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('user_manage.php','_self') </script>";
  }

}

?>
```

Please note that the code shown here does not change the filename when storing the files on the server. This will cause problems when two person upload pictures with same filename. You need to implement an appropriate solution for that.